# Tension is not equal to $m g \cos \theta$ in a simple pendulum. Why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

$l$ is constant but $T(t) \neq m g \cos \theta(t)$.

Why?

Please explain intuitively.

Comment: Please edit the question to reduce the size of the graphic.

Comment: Why did you set $T = mg \cos \theta$ in the first place?  Why not $T \cos \theta = mg$?

Comment: The system moves along an arc, and forces are needed to do so. The forces can only come from gravity and the tension. So the tension is such to make the object track an arc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever an object follows a circular path then a [centripetal force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) is required to explain such(the change in direction). The force is given by $F_{centripetal } = m \frac {v^2}{l}$. Therefore here rather than being $T - m g \cos \theta =0$ it is $T - m g \cos \theta =m \frac {v^2}{l}$

[Note: Here $v$ is the instantaneous velocity and varies from one moment to another (as there is tangential component of gravity acting on it)]

Comment: $F_r = m (\ddot{r} - r \dot{\theta}^2)$ and $F_\phi = m (r \ddot{\theta} + 2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta})$. $r = l$. $\dot{r} = 0$. So $F_r = -m l \dot{\theta}^2$ and $F_\phi = m l \ddot{\theta}$. Does $F_r = T - m g \cos \theta = m \frac{v^2}{l}$ hold?

Comment: @tchappy Yes, it does for every instant. But as you see that tangential velocity $v$ varies from one moment to other(as there is tangential component of gravity acting on it) therefore you would be required to know tangential velocity as a function of time

Comment: @tchappy [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/508636/238497) is somewhat related to your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The end mass rotates, thus you have a centripetal force added.

Comment: I don’t know that I’ve seen the end mass rotating in a pendulum derivation before, how would this help OP?

Comment: @KyleKanos I think it's worded poorly; but when you consider that the end mass rotates _about the pivot_, it does actually shine some light on OP's problem; though it could be much clearer.